# Accessing java class from php and html page to obtain a value

Tags: java, php, html, jsp

I have a web application developed using Java or JSP.  It works fine on my laptop (`localhost`).  On loading the index.jsp page, a java class is called (from index dot jsp) which returns a sound file to the client, and on clicking a play button the sound plays, during which some timing data are collected, analyzed by another jsp page (analyze.jsp) and the result is submitted to the database.

My question is that I want to be able to call this java class from any website developed using (php or html) and I want it to work the same way as it did on index.jsp.  This could also be on the same or different domain.  Please how can I accomplish this?  For instance, how can I call the java class to generate a sound file for me on a php page or html?

========

@Luiggi, I call my java class from index.jsp using this code:

```
<%
    GetToken gt= new GetToken();
    String tokenVal = gt.myToken();
%>
```

Comment: You can try to convert your app to a webservice app

Comment: How you *call* your Java class from your *index.jsp* file?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, please see answer to your question.  Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that your view is highly coupled to your Java code. You should move the business logic to a Servlet and access to it through it. You can learn the basics about Servlets in [StackOverflow Servlets wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)